# Android: Enable Haptic Feedback and Sound on Key Click

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I'm having an issue manipulating the system settings in Android. To make a long story short we are developing an app that conducts some user experiments using different input settings. We will need to enable and disable sound on key clicks and vibration on key clicks programmatically through the different experiments.

I've explored a few options, but would like to avoid actually setting up a listener and manually vibrating if at all possible.

I have given myself permission to modify system settings:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

The following is the code I'm using to modify the system settings:

```
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
             android.provider.Settings.System.HAPTIC_FEEDBACK_ENABLED,
             1);
```

The changes are however not reflected in the system settings.

The following code is working, verified by the fact that the settings actually change in the system settings window on the emulator.

```
   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
             android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_AUTO_PUNCTUATE,
             0);

   android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
             android.provider.Settings.System.TEXT_AUTO_REPLACE,
             0);
```

I have also tried setting the specific settings on the view, as such:

```
    EditText inputArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    inputArea.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
    inputArea.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP, HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING | HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_VIEW_SETTING);
    inputArea.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.VIRTUAL_KEY, HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_GLOBAL_SETTING | HapticFeedbackConstants.FLAG_IGNORE_VIEW_SETTING);
```

I've pushed this to the phone and it has no effect on there either.

What I need is a way to programmatically enable/disable haptic feedback and sound on key clicks during the experiment. I've searched stack overflow but haven't been able to find anything useful.

Anyone know any tricks or will I have to relegate myself to using the key press handlers and manually vibrating the phone?

Thanks!

Comment: Setting up a listener and manually vibrating is the correct approach here (this is what `performHapticFeedback` method is for). Why are trying to avoid it?